# Android: What to set contentdescription to so talk back doesn't say anything

Tags: android, accessibility

I have some images that are impossible for visually impaired users to use at all. I want to  be consistent in my code so I have content descriptions.  Is there a specific string that will make it so Talkback doesn't say anything when the user touches the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  Previous answer was to not add the tag in XML.  The correct answer is to add the value "@null".  This prevents a string from being spoken (same as an adding the attribute), but @null will also prevent the LINT tool from yelling at you about a missing attribute.